# Why class is not applying on input element if it's invalid in Template driven form Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I used a template driven form for my login page. I want a red border on input elements if they are invalid or have any errors but the class `borderRed` is not being added on an input element when the input is blank or invalid.

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && signin()" #f="ngForm" class="m-login__form m-form" action="">
  <ng-template #alertSignin></ng-template>

  <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
    <label>
      Email <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <input [class.borderRed]="email.invalid" class="form-control m-input" type="text" required="required" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label">
    <label [pTooltip]="attachementTooltipmsg" tooltipPosition="top" for="form_control_1">
      Password <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>
    <input [class.borderRed]="password.invalid" class="form-control m-input" required="" name="password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel">
  </div>

  <div class="m-login__form-action">
    <button [disabled]="loading" [ngClass]="{'m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light': loading}" id="m_login_signin_submit" class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air">
      Sign In
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide a small repro with stackblitz?

Comment: in your password input why is required field like `required=""`

Comment: try to console log email.invalid when it should trigger a change.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
   <input [class.borderRed]="email.touched && !email.valid" class="form-control m-input" type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
```

Check out StackBiltz

[Edited code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qd3gbf)

Answer (score 1):

Angular adds some css classes when an input is valid or not. You can override the css to make it look as you want. With this approach you don't have to do `[class.borderRed]=...` on every input. https://angular.io/guide/forms

```
.ng-valid[required], .ng-valid.required  {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<input [ngClass]="{'borderRed':email.invalid}" class="form-control m-input" type="text" required="required" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Actually I got both methods to work - did you define border red?  See this: https://angular-cic9xb.stackblitz.io

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6r5tt - ignore the other link this has the edit so you can see it working

Answer (score 0):

For email validation add the `email` directive for example 
`<input type="email" name="email" ngModel email>`

Or you can use the `pattern` attribute, example :

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
              <input type="text"
                [ngModel] = "user.email" name="email"
                #email="ngModel" id="inputEmail"
                placeholder="Email"
                pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
                required>
            </div>

<!-- This is the error section -->

<div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf = "email.errors?.required">
        Email field can't be blank
    </div>
    <div *ngIf = "email.errors?.pattern && email.touched">
        The email id doesn't seem right
    </div>
 </div>
```

Also better mark the fields required just by adding `required`. For password input you can use a validator like this `minlength ="8"`.

Generally you have to specify the validations rules. 
In reactive forms you would specify that in the component class for example :

`this.myForm = this.f.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required ],
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. this works for me:-

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="fullnameControl.invalid && (fullnameControl.dirty || fullnameControl.touched)" 
        [class.has-success]="fullnameControl.valid">
            <label class="control-label">Full Name Field </label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                required
                class="form-control" 
                name="fullname" 
                id="fullname" [(ngModel)]="fullname"
                #fullnameControl="ngModel"

            />
            <span class="help-block" 
               *ngIf="fullnameControl.invalid && (fullnameControl.dirty 
              || fullnameControl.touched)">Full Name is required. </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass for dynamically adding different classes.
Example:

```
     <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName" [ngClass]="{
            'has-success': firstName.valid,
            'has-danger': (firstName.invalid && firstName.dirty) || (!isFormSubmitted && firstName.invalid)}">
```

If **FirstName** is invalid and dirty (user has actually touched this field), then add **has-danger** class.
If **firstName** is valid, then add **has-success** class.
**Note:** **firstName** is a form-control